# Add environment variable to install4j

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to add environment variable to install4j once, instead of add this variable under the "Specify environment variable" field?

for example i want to add JAVA_VENDOR=Sun once and each time i will use "Run executable or batch file" action this variable will be recognized by the running process.

Thanks in Advance, 
Maxim

Comment: Unfortunately this is currently not possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with setx command.

See setx /? for more info.

```
Setx "JAVA_VENDOR" "Sun once"
```

PD: Remember the CMD uses the set profile at this moment, I mean if you try to ser a voiremental variable directly in a CMD instance you'll need to close and re-open cmd to see the changes.

Bye.